# Detect dismissal of UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to present a view, after UIActivityViewController will move to parent VC

```
...
UIActivityViewController *avvc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:avvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
[avvc setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    NSLog(@"after dismiss");
    //Present another VC
}];
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: This answer is now deprecated, use @Bijoy Thangaraj answer below instead.

Comment: what is more is that this completion is called every time when action finishes, NOT ONLY WHEN DISMISSED

Comment: So, this is not the actually dismiss handler. Because if user selects an activity and then cancels the action on new activity screen. UIActivityViewController doesn't dismissed but this completion handler gets called.

Comment: How to find the actual dismissHandler.

Answer (score 38):

**Swift 3 Version**

```
avvc.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
   if completed {
      // Do something 
   }
}
```

Comment: The boolean value `completed` represents the completion state of the individual `UIActivity`.  If the `UIActivityViewController` is dismissed without any action, the value for `activityType` will be nil and the value of completed will be `false`.

Comment: In the OP's scenario, the view controller won't be dismissed if they cancel the share activity.

Answer (score 8):

I just want to clarify that the boolean value `completed` represents the completion state of the individual `UIActivity`. If the `UIActivityViewController` is dismissed without any action, the value for `activityType` will be `nil` and the value of completed will be `false`.

```
[avvc setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(UIActivityType _Nullable activityType, BOOL completed,
                                      NSArray * _Nullable returnedItems,
                                      NSError * _Nullable activityError) {

    if (activityType == nil)    {
        NSLog(@"UIActivityViewController dismissed without any action.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"completionWithItemsHandler, activityType: %@, completed: %d, returnedItems: %@, activityError: %@",
         activityType, completed, returnedItems, activityError);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 6):

## **Xamarin / C#**

```
avvc.CompletionWithItemsHandler = MyCompletionWithItemsHandler;

// ...

void MyCompletionWithItemsHandler(NSString activityType, bool completed, NSExtensionItem[] returnedItems, NSError error)
{
    if (completed)
    {
        // Did not tap Cancel
    } 
    else
    {
        // Cancel was tapped
    }
}
```